# Why does my Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm fail?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Yes, I know the Sieve of Eratosthenes is in the standard library Prime class, but I'm trying to implement myself for an exercise.

I'm following the description on Wikipedia word for word:

> To find all the prime numbers less than or equal to a given integer n by Eratosthenes' method:
>   1. Create a list of consecutive integers from 2 through n: (2, 3, 4, ..., n).
>   2. Initially, let p equal 2, the first prime number.
>   3. Starting from p, enumerate its multiples by counting to n in increments of p, and mark them in the list (these will be 2p, 3p, 4p, ... ; the p itself should not be marked).
>   4. Find the first number greater than p in the list that is not marked. If there was no such number, stop. Otherwise, let p now equal this new number (which is the next prime), and repeat from step 3.
>   5. When the algorithm terminates, all the numbers in the list that are not marked are prime.

```
def sieve(n)
    # Create a list of consecutive integers from 2 through n.   
    list = [*2..n] # [2, 3, 4, 5, etc]
    p = 2 # Let p equal 2, the first prime number

    # Starting from p, enumerate its multiples by counting to n in in increments of p
    loop do
        p1 = p # We'll use this to count in increments, by adding the initial value of p to p each iteration
        until p >= n 
            p += p1
            list.delete(p) # Mark all multiples of p in the list
        end
        if list.find{|x| x > p}
            p = list.find{|x| x > p} # p now equals the first number greater than p in the list that is not marked (deleted)
        else
            return list
        end
    end
end
```

But the output of `sieve(20)` is `[2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]`, obviously it's just counting 2 by 2.

I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 4):

You are changing p, so it is not 2 in `list.find{|x| x > p}`. Maybe you would like to change this part of the code to `list.find{|x| x > p1}`.

Comment: Damn, that didn't even occur to me. Thanks a ton IvayloPetrov, that fixes it.